# xslt replace attribute value from a recursive copy

Tags: xslt

i need to replace an attribute value in a recursive copy of an xml with namespace
the attribute is actionCode that has value Replace in the source file. i need to replace it with value Change
this is my file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<SyncPulseTask releaseID="10.1.3" xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2">
<ApplicationArea>
    <Sender>
        <LogicalID>infor.engine.pulse</LogicalID>
        <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
    </Sender>
    <CreationDateTime>2014-09-29T15:47:27.140Z</CreationDateTime>
</ApplicationArea>
<DataArea>
    <Sync>
        <TenantID>infor</TenantID>
        <ActionCriteria>
            <ActionExpression actionCode="Replace"/>
        </ActionCriteria>
    </Sync>
</DataArea>
</SyncPulseTask>
```

this is my xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" xmlns:a="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"                 exclude-result-prefixes="a" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">     <!-- source bod name -->
    <ProcessPulseTask>                     <!-- target bod name -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="a:ApplicationArea"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="a:DataArea"/>
    </ProcessPulseTask>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="a:ApplicationArea">
    <ApplicationArea>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </ApplicationArea>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="a:DataArea">
    <DataArea>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="a:Sync"/>
    </DataArea>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="a:Sync">             <!-- source verb type -->
  <Process>                              <!-- target verb type -->
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
  </Process>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the result is

```
<ProcessPulseTask xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2">
<ApplicationArea>
    <Sender>
        <LogicalID>infor.engine.pulse</LogicalID>
        <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
    </Sender>
    <CreationDateTime>2014-09-29T15:47:27.140Z</CreationDateTime>
</ApplicationArea>
<DataArea>
    <Process>
        <TenantID>infor</TenantID>
        <ActionCriteria>
            <ActionExpression actionCode="Replace"></ActionExpression>
        </ActionCriteria>
    </Process>
</DataArea>
</ProcessPulseTask>
```

How can i replace the value Replace from the attribute actionCode with Change?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

If that's the only change you want to make, why don't you do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:a="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"
exclude-result-prefixes="a">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:ActionExpression/@actionCode[.='Replace']">
    <xsl:attribute name="actionCode">Change</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit:

I haven't noticed the additional change pointed out by Martin Honnen. You could handle that by adding another template:

```
<xsl:template match="a:Sync">
    <Process xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </Process>
</xsl:template>
```

or, as Martin suggests (and you already have in your version), make `xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"` the *default namespace* for the entire stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"
xmlns:a="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"
exclude-result-prefixes="a">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:ActionExpression/@actionCode[.='Replace']">
    <xsl:attribute name="actionCode">Change</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:Sync">
    <Process>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </Process>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It's the right approach and the easily allows to make the other changes with e.g. `<xsl:template match="a:Sync"><Process><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:template>` if you add `xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your reply, but as you have seen this is not the only change i need to do, i have to modify also Sync with Processs and SyncPulseTask with ProcessPulseTask as i did in my example, how can i put your code in my above?